# Laravel preserving changes to external libraries

Tags: laravel, dependencies

I have installed jwt auth library for laravel. To match my application's needs , I need to make some changes to it. 
However, whenever I do a composer update or install, the changes are gone. Is there a way to stop this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume when you say:

> I need to make some changes to it.

You've been editing the package files in the `vendor` directory for the jwt library. Anything within the `vendor` directory will be overwritten with a composer update/install. You therefore shouldn't be changing/editing files in the `vendor` directory.

You should instead look at utilising the library in a different way by perhaps extending a class which you need to use or you could possibly fork the project and pull in your own modified version.

If you provide further details on how you want to utilise it and what changes you want to make to it perhaps you would get some suggestions on how best to approach this.

**Edit**

I'm guessing this is how you would do make and use your own modified copy...

Fork the project on github, I assume you're using this one https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth (therefore it is on github)

Clone it to get a local copy, make your changes, push the changes back to github. Then finally use composer to pull your forked/modified version in to your project. It would then be accessible from the vendor folder again!

Some further info:

> [Loading a package from a VCS repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)
>
> There are a few use cases for this. The most common one is maintaining
>   your own fork of a third party library. If you are using a certain
>   library for your project and you decide to change something in the
>   library, you will want your project to use the patched version. If the
>   library is on GitHub (this is the case most of the time), you can
>   simply fork it there and push your changes to your fork. After that
>   you update the project's composer.json. All you have to do is add your
>   fork as a repository and update the version constraint to point to
>   your custom branch. Your custom branch name must be prefixed with
>   "dev-".

Comment: I do want to fork it. Where should I copy the directory from  vendor to ?

Comment: Updated the answer to address your last comment. Hope that helps!